# Is it possible to joining multiple row

Tags: postgresql

I am looking for a way to join two rows with same value (promo code in my case). So for example, I have a table:

```
ID  PROMO_CODE   PROMO_NAME   DESCRIPTION       LANGUAGE
1   PC123        ABC          Desc in English   ENG
2   PC123        CBA          Desc in Español   ESP
```

and I want the result like:

```
ID PROMO_CODE  PROMO_NAME_ENG  PROMO_NAME_ESP  DESCRIPTION_ENG   DESCRIPTION_ESP
1  PC123       ABC             CBA             Desc in English   Desc in Español
```

Any help will be appreciate

Comment: Is there always both rows? If not, which language is guaranteed to exist?

Comment: for now it always both rows, but it can be more than two in the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join on `PROMO_CODE`:

```
select
  a.ID,
  a.PROMO_CODE,
  a.PROMO_NAME as PROMO_NAME_ENG,
  b.PROMO_NAME as PROMO_NAME_ESP,
  a.DESCRIPTION as DESCRIPTION_ENG,
  b.DESCRIPTION as DESCRIPTION_ESP
from mytable a
left join mytable b on b.PROMO_CODE = a.PROMO_CODE
  and b.LANGUAGE = 'ESP'
where a.LANGUAGE = 'ENG'
```

Using a *left* join guarantees the `ENG` data even if the `ESP` data doesn't exist, which seems possible due to `ENG`'s `ID` being in the output, but not `ESP`'s `ID`